# How to loop through properties with specific index

Tags: c#

I have a class with `50 properties` and I like to loop the properties say from 8 to 24.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(myclass).GetProperties(); 

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) // How to say loop from 8 to 24
{
     property.SetValue(property, value, null);
}
```

Comment: Property order is not specified; you probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: SLaks is right, you shouldn't do that. But assuming you're going to, what in this example is wrong with you just writing `for (int i = 8; i <= 24; i++) { properties[i].SetValue(o, value, null); }`? (I changed the `property` argument to `o` here, because `property` makes no sense.)

Answer (score 1):

To select range of items from a collection you can use `Enumerable.Skip` and `Enumerable.Take`.

```
 var range = typeof(myclass).GetProperties().Skip(8).Take(24-8);
```

Note that there is no formally defined order for properties (also it is unlikely that order returned by `GetProperties` will change at least on the same machine).

It is better to select groups of properties based on some well defined criteria like type, presence of particular custom attribute, visibility.

Comment: I see what you mean, I had a work around of dividing properties into their relevant class a placing a if condition..

Comment: @Mr.Info I'd recommend updating your question with information about what you actually trying to achieve... There probably either totally different way OR maybe just tweak of code in my sample with some `Where` filtering.